# Socket application does not work over the internet

Tags: c++, sockets, connect

I've got a problem in socket programming. I'm currently writing a simple server/client application which asks connecting clients to answer a survey (I'm following the exercises in the book: TCP/IP Sockets in C: Practical guide for Programmers). It works fine in my local network (using localhost to connect), but I can't make it work over the internet.
Since I changed some of the code found in the book, I tried to compile the original source code from the book but it still doesn't work. I assume this is not a code problem but a network problem.
I did some research and so I turned off my firewall, I forwarded the port I'm using (12543) in my router but it still doesn't work... I've got a remote windows server running Windows 7 for testing: when I run my server on it and try to connect from my computer it fails, when I try to run my server from my computer and try to connect from the remote windows server: it fails again. Even when I run my server on my computer and try to connect with the client from the same computer using my private IPv4 address 192.168.x.x or my public one, it fails ! Oh, and there is no firewall running on the windows server.

I really don't know what to do now... I can ping my windows server from my computer, I can ping my computer from my windows server, but it's impossible to connect to my application.

The source code can be found here: http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/practical/CSockets2/textcode.html (SurveyServer2.cpp, SurveyClient2.cpp, SurveyCommon.h), but I don't think it's a code problem.
Please tell me if it's not clear enough. And excuse me if I did some grammatical errors, I'm french!

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT :** Ok, I know what's going on: it's a compatibility issue between IPv4 and IPv6! It's not properly working yet, but I now know what to fix. Thanks everybody :)

**SECOND EDIT :** Well, I think I finally understood. I was binding my server to a IPv6 address, but the host my server is running on only have a public IPv4 address. When I tried to connect, the DNS resolution only returned a IPv4 address so I was unable to connect to my server. I told to getaddrinfo to return only IPv4 addresses, so now it binds on a IPv4 address and it works fine.

There is surely a way to add a IPv6 address to my host but I don't think I will need it, it works okay right now, I hope this doesn't cause any trouble.

Comment: have you tried it with port 80?

Comment: It sounds like a network configuration issue, the firewalls can be in many different places: you've got the Windows firewall on your PC, one on the router, one on the router where the server is and one on the server itself, not to mention various filters that can happen on the way. Try to use some standard port like 80 and see if it works (although if the server has an HTTP server running it might be a problem).

Comment: You should show your socket code for setting up your listener so that we can completely rule out that it is not a code problem.

Comment: You have a contradiction here that hinders our troubleshooting abilities. You said "It works fine in my local network" but farther down said that you tried to run both client and server on the same computer and connect locally which failed. It cannot "work on the local network" and yet not work on the local computer.

Comment: Further, since it's impossible to have something "not work on the local computer" but yet have it "work on the local network," this suggests your method of connecting is at fault more than where you are connecting to/from. Check out Thomas' answer. Now notice that you said it failed when supplied the local LAN IP address, but succeeded when you used "localhost" host name. Perhaps you should check out that avenue further.

Comment: thats interesting, will you keep this post up2date please? Someone should mark it as wiki if you told us, what you have done to fix it, if you get it fixed.

Comment: Sure, I will. For now, I "fixed" it by specifying to getaddrinfo that I only want IPv4 addresses, but it's not the way I want it to work so I'll keep searching and update when it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code makes usage of `getaddrinfo` and need a hostname not a IP address.

Comment: As I pointed out above, it looks like his own troubleshooting might verify this, if I can make the assumption in my second comment about his contradiction being interpreted as "It works when I use 'localhost' but not when I use the IP address.

Comment: You were right, I tried using my computer name instead of my ip address and it worked, but I still can't connect to my remote windows server running the server. I tried using its hostname but I didn't work.

Comment: @Zoneur, then you should check your DNS Settings as pointed out in the comments to your question.

Comment: I don't understand why it works with the host name and not with 127.0.0.1. It is said on msdn.microsoft.com that the getaddrinfo function can take a hostname or a dotted IPv4 address or a IPv6 address. It works with my computer name, with ::1 or with my local IPv6 address but not with 127.0.0.1.. Is it normal ?

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like you have a connectivity issue or a DNS issue.

Ensure the name resolution is working:

Enter 'ping server_NAME' on the command line of the client machine.
If it can't find an IP address for the server name that could be your issue.

Ensure connectivity:

On the server command line:

enter 'netstat -an -p TCP'. This will show a list of all programs listening and their port numbers. You should see your server listening on port 12543.

On the machine where you are running your client program:

Use telnet to see if you can get through to the server. You can set the port number telnet uses with a command line option. Usually something like 'telnet -p 12543 server-ip'. If it says 'connection refused' then there's a connectivity issue (a firewall/etc). If it opens a connection you will get no error message and you will be able to type text to be sent to the server. You really only care if telnet was able to establish a tcp connection here.

If Telnet does connect then your issue is communication between the programs and not a network issue.

Comment: This server, when launched, listens on both 12543 and 12544. Clients connecting on the first port answer a survey, and the client connecting from the same host as the server and on the port 12544 can see how many people answered the survey, it's an admin client. When I entered the netstat command after running my server, I could see it listening on the port 12544 (the admin one) binded to 127.0.0.1, but not on the port 12543. But I can still connect to it using the client if I use "localhost", how is that possible ? I tried using telnet, but it failed.

Comment: Ok so -p does not work under windows, I removed it and saw the server running and listening on the good port. But I still can't establish the connection with telnet... I'll keep searching why, thank you!